# Detailed query of PostgreSQL unix process

Tags: linux, postgresql, process

When I type `ps aux` in the console window to look which process of PostgesSQL eats all CPU, I receive such results:

```
$ ps aux | grep postgres
postgres: username dbname 127.0.0.1(39352) SELECT                                                                      
postgres: username dbname 127.0.0.1(39414) SELECT
```

Is it possible to configure PGSQL to receive results like?

```
$ ps aux | grep postgres
postgres: username dbname 127.0.0.1(39352) SELECT id FROM clients WHERE ...                                                                      
postgres: username dbname 127.0.0.1(39414) INSERT INTO users (...
```

Answer (score 1):

No it is not possible. Theoretically you can modify PostgreSQL server source code, but probably nobody does it. The correct solution is query to `pg_stat_activity` table, when you need detail informations.

```
[pavel@dhcppc2 citext]$ psql -c "select datname, client_addr, state, query from pg_stat_activity"
┌──────────┬─────────────┬────────┬─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ datname  │ client_addr │ state  │                              query                              │
╞══════════╪═════════════╪════════╪═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╡
│ postgres │ ( null )    │ active │ select datname, client_addr, state, query from pg_stat_activity │
└──────────┴─────────────┴────────┴─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

(1 row)